# Learning parameters of each simulated device

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

Does tensorflow-federated support assigning different hyper-parameters(like batch-size or learning rate) for different simulated devices?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you may find this a bit unnatural, but yes, such a thing is possible.

One approach to doing this that is supported today is to have each client take its local learning rate as a top-level parameter, and use this in the training. A dummy example here would be (sliding the model parameter in the computations below) something along the lines of

```
@tff.tf_computation(tff.SequenceTyoe(...), tf.float32)
def train_with_learning_rate(ds, lr):
  # run training with `tf.data.Dataset` ds and learning rate lr
  ...

@tff.federated_computation(tff.FederatedType([tff.SequenceType(...), tf.float32])
def run_one_round(datasets_and_lrs):
  return tff.federated_mean(
      tff.federated_map(train_with_learning_rate, datasets_and_lrs))
```

Invoking the federated computation here with a list of tuples with the first element of the tuple representing the clients data and the second element representing the particular client's learning rate, would give what you want.

Such a thing requires writing custom federated computations, and in particular likely defining your own `IterativeProcess`. A similar iterative process definition was recently open sourced [here, link goes to the relevant local client function definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/4d29cf22753044df6fdd50711ea3b18286b50b7d/tensorflow_federated/python/research/optimization/shared/fed_avg_schedule.py#L293) to allow for learning rate scheduling on the clients by taking an extra integer parameter representing the round number, it is likely a good place to look.